# ScrollView is not showing custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I've tried a lot of solutions asked in the similar questions on stackoverflow but they are either outdated or are not working.
I've added a `UIScrollView` on my `UIViewController` and made a custom `.xib` where I've created my long (1336 height) view and want to show it on the `scrollView`. So in `ViewDidAppear()` I've added this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1500)
scrollView.addSubview(mainView)
```

Declared `let mainView: MainView = MainView()` on top of the class. When I run it, the scroll view just shows blank with no subview but swiping up shows the vertical scroll bar which means the height `1500` is working but the subview is not showing.

Comment: have you tried using the bringSubviewToFront method? Also, you could try setting the frame for mainView while initialising.

Comment: Please give more info about your MainView is that just a UIVIew or something else?

Comment: @ThePedestrian the answer below where the instantiate xib is happening is the solution but there is a problem as MainView is out of width bounds of scroll view.

Comment: @ChaudharyTalha use autolayout constraint and set equal width for the mainView and the view containing scrollview. Also align the scroll view horizontally center wrt container view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
let nib = UINib(nibName: <ViewName>, bundle: bundle)
let mainView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! MainView
```

**Explanation** :

To instantiate xib above format is used. Please try this and then add it to your `UIScrollView`.

Let me know it it worked

**Update:**
To set the custom frame, we need to give frame to `mainview` object..

```
mainView.frame = scrollView.bounds
```

Comment: It worked just had to get rid of some swift 3 errors but the content in main view is getting out of frame width of scrollview. I've checked both scroll view and main view have same width.